# Tox doesn't find pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, tox, pyproject.toml

It seems that I cannot manage `tox` to see my `pyproject.toml`. I've created a minimal example:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ cat <<EOF > pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["cython", "setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.tox]
envlist = "py310"

[tool.tox.testenv]
deps = ["pytest"]
commands = ["pytest"]
EOF
$ ls
 ls
pyproject.toml
$ tox
ROOT: No tox.ini or setup.cfg or pyproject.toml found, assuming empty tox.ini at /home/user/testtox
...
$ tox --version
ROOT: No tox.ini or setup.cfg or pyproject.toml found, assuming empty tox.ini at /home/ycr/testtox
4.14.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tox/__init__.py
```

Note that if I `touch tox.ini` it finds it :(

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for tox-related section in `pyproject.toml` is very strange:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["cython", "setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
[tox]
envlist = py310

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest
"""
```

See [the docs](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.1/config.html#pyproject-toml).

PS. In my not so humble opinion it would be better and nicer to move this to `tox.ini`.

Comment: My complete usecase use a much bigger `pyproject.toml`. The purpose of `.toml`is to avoid having a `tox.ini`. So Tox should be able to read it from `.toml`.

Comment: @nowox Sure, no problem, the answer shows how to do that. The link to the docs is also there.

Comment: I check that tomorrow and mark as answered if it solves the issue.

Comment: @nowox Any progress in checking?

Comment: Yes it works, but it would have been better to leverage .toml format instead of this `legacy_tox_ini` string. I cannot upvote your answer, you need to edit it first :(

Comment: @nowox "*…it would have been better to leverage .toml format instead of this `legacy_tox_ini` string.*" Not my fault. :-) I can guess `tox` author(s) want to have one parser for `tox.ini`, they slurp `legacy_tox_ini` from `pyproject.toml` and push it to the parser. "*I cannot upvote your answer, you need to edit it first*" Edited :-)